Программ в рандомный момент может остановится без ошибки на вечно
import requests
from  bs4  import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import time 
import json
import sqlite3
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent(browsers=['chrome'])


def download_img(url,data_id):   
    try:
        pyt_do_file = f"C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/diplom/IMG_BASE/filee_IMG_{data_id}.jpg"

        response = requests.get(url=url) 
        with open(pyt_do_file, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)
            
        return pyt_do_file
    
    except Exception as _ex:
        print(_ex)
        return 'the file is not installed .'



def download_file(data_id):  
    #'https://mcbuild.org/schematics/14495:amphitheatre-arena',  
    try:
        cookies = {
            '_ga': 'GA1.1.181025297.1713956099',
            '_pk_id.78.90ce': 'eff7a471c03e4887.1713956100.',
            'PHPSESSID': 'd04933f9eabea1b76bfd1247fb31f270',
            '_pk_ses.78.90ce': '1',
            '_ga_PT57S4LEXC': 'GS1.1.1714573040.18.1.1714573303.0.0.0',
            'FCNEC': '%5B%5B%22AKsRol-5DouioWBi4EHE9XuU6m0GRGrn5Fp7cpBM23AMwbaFWwhvpE1hd7PFOtzKhW8mZ190hL75xunqYeTtZJsubx9tCxP2ej_Q-LpH5V9hFLggtgLVDq3560la15Iy3rFbxA8Au2MyEoj08ok7UbpjpxAy8dXoGA%3D%3D%22%5D%5D',
            '__gads': 'ID=2c17f14da703eb96:T=1713956101:RT=1714573351:S=ALNI_MYWB4XIXp5dIiU4sWQigy7hWVbIWg',
            '__gpi': 'UID=00000dfdb98c2625:T=1713956101:RT=1714573351:S=ALNI_Mb0ZgMl2axV8rOhTX1js0iV5JdCVg',
            '__eoi': 'ID=2aa11ed4288f8e9b:T=1713956101:RT=1714573351:S=AA-AfjbfMART8WjkvaR2nKyUDjbu',
        }

        headers = {
            'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
            'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
            'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
            # 'cookie': '_ga=GA1.1.181025297.1713956099; _pk_id.78.90ce=eff7a471c03e4887.1713956100.; PHPSESSID=d04933f9eabea1b76bfd1247fb31f270; _pk_ses.78.90ce=1; _ga_PT57S4LEXC=GS1.1.1714573040.18.1.1714573303.0.0.0; FCNEC=%5B%5B%22AKsRol-5DouioWBi4EHE9XuU6m0GRGrn5Fp7cpBM23AMwbaFWwhvpE1hd7PFOtzKhW8mZ190hL75xunqYeTtZJsubx9tCxP2ej_Q-LpH5V9hFLggtgLVDq3560la15Iy3rFbxA8Au2MyEoj08ok7UbpjpxAy8dXoGA%3D%3D%22%5D%5D; __gads=ID=2c17f14da703eb96:T=1713956101:RT=1714573351:S=ALNI_MYWB4XIXp5dIiU4sWQigy7hWVbIWg; __gpi=UID=00000dfdb98c2625:T=1713956101:RT=1714573351:S=ALNI_Mb0ZgMl2axV8rOhTX1js0iV5JdCVg; __eoi=ID=2aa11ed4288f8e9b:T=1713956101:RT=1714573351:S=AA-AfjbfMART8WjkvaR2nKyUDjbu',
            'priority': 'u=0, i',
            'referer': 'https://mcbuild.org/schematics/',
            'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="124", "Google Chrome";v="124", "Not-A.Brand";v="99"',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
            'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
            'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
            'user-agent': f'{ua.random}',
        }

        response = requests.get(f'https://mcbuild.org/download/schematic={data_id}',timeout=30, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup (response.text,'lxml')
        file_url = str(soup.find_all('script')[3]).split("'")[1]

    
        response = requests.get(f"https://mcbuild.org{file_url})",timeout=30, headers={'Referer': f'https://mcbuild.org/download/schematic={data_id}'})
        
        pyt_do_file = f'C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/diplom/shema_base/filee_shem_{data_id}.schematic'     
        with open(pyt_do_file, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)

        return pyt_do_file
        
    except Exception as _ex:
        print(_ex)
        return 'the file is not installed .'

def Sqlite_base_loading(name,soup,pytt_file_imgg,pytt_file_schem,PAGE,connection):
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    obgect = soup.find('div',class_='col-md-4 col-6 mb-4 pb-2')
    tip = obgect.find('div',class_='w-100 mt-auto').find('p',class_='fs-7 card-text text-white').text 
    tip = tip.replace('Flying','')
    tip = tip.replace(' ','')

    if PAGE == 0 :
        cursor.execute(f'''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {tip} (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT NOT NULL,
        pytt_imgg TEXT NOT NULL,
        pytt_schem TEXT NOT NULL 
        )
        ''')    

        connection.commit()
    
    cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO {tip} (name,pytt_imgg,pytt_schem) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (name,pytt_file_imgg,pytt_file_schem))
    
    connection.commit()


def  click_more() :

    #response = requests.get('https://mcbuild.org/schematics/')
    #soup = BeautifulSoup (response.text,'lxml')
    #kol_tipov = len(soup.find('ul',class_='nav nav-pills mb-4 justify-content-start fs-7').find_all('li',class_='nav-item me-2 mb-2'))

    kol_tipov = 20

    Id = 1
    PAGE = 0

    n = 0
    liust = []

    connection = sqlite3.connect('C:/Users/ACER/Desktop/diplom/postrouki_data_base_pars.db')

    while True :
        if Id == 13:
            Id += 1

        cookies = {
            '_ga': 'GA1.1.181025297.1713956099',
            '_pk_id.78.90ce': 'eff7a471c03e4887.1713956100.',
            'PHPSESSID': 'd04933f9eabea1b76bfd1247fb31f270',
            '_pk_ses.78.90ce': '1',
            '__gads': 'ID=2c17f14da703eb96:T=1713956101:RT=1714238239:S=ALNI_MYWB4XIXp5dIiU4sWQigy7hWVbIWg',
            '__gpi': 'UID=00000dfdb98c2625:T=1713956101:RT=1714238239:S=ALNI_Mb0ZgMl2axV8rOhTX1js0iV5JdCVg',
            '__eoi': 'ID=2aa11ed4288f8e9b:T=1713956101:RT=1714238239:S=AA-AfjbfMART8WjkvaR2nKyUDjbu',
            '_ga_PT57S4LEXC': 'GS1.1.1714238238.9.1.1714238300.0.0.0',
            'FCNEC': '%5B%5B%22AKsRol_Mi2U-YgkZs3vyrMk5UsRTTEeNRx1v6LGOqAzWJRRi-4EoINMNxh6WnFCg6h6J3UNqDfvKqonh5l4delYN0gjP8g1Tk3PyYZ70UczjfkeoOyR9gvIj0whYCDNBGxtzX4p6z-1SuAjm7QkmD0eJBNjRV9vCVw%3D%3D%22%5D%5D',
        }

        headers = {
            'accept': '*/*',
            'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            # 'cookie': '_ga=GA1.1.181025297.1713956099; _pk_id.78.90ce=eff7a471c03e4887.1713956100.; PHPSESSID=d04933f9eabea1b76bfd1247fb31f270; _pk_ses.78.90ce=1; __gads=ID=2c17f14da703eb96:T=1713956101:RT=1714238239:S=ALNI_MYWB4XIXp5dIiU4sWQigy7hWVbIWg; __gpi=UID=00000dfdb98c2625:T=1713956101:RT=1714238239:S=ALNI_Mb0ZgMl2axV8rOhTX1js0iV5JdCVg; __eoi=ID=2aa11ed4288f8e9b:T=1713956101:RT=1714238239:S=AA-AfjbfMART8WjkvaR2nKyUDjbu; _ga_PT57S4LEXC=GS1.1.1714238238.9.1.1714238300.0.0.0; FCNEC=%5B%5B%22AKsRol_Mi2U-YgkZs3vyrMk5UsRTTEeNRx1v6LGOqAzWJRRi-4EoINMNxh6WnFCg6h6J3UNqDfvKqonh5l4delYN0gjP8g1Tk3PyYZ70UczjfkeoOyR9gvIj0whYCDNBGxtzX4p6z-1SuAjm7QkmD0eJBNjRV9vCVw%3D%3D%22%5D%5D',
            'origin': 'https://mcbuild.org',
            'priority': 'u=1, i',
            'referer': 'https://mcbuild.org/schematics/',
            'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="124", "Google Chrome";v="124", "Not-A.Brand";v="99"',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
            'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
            'user-agent': f'{ua.random}',
            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        }

        data = {
            'id': f'{Id}',
            'page': f'{PAGE}',
        }


        response = requests.post('https://mcbuild.org/items/', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, data=data)
        soup = BeautifulSoup (response.text,'lxml')
        obgect_list = soup.find_all('div',class_='col-md-4 col-6 mb-4 pb-2')

             
        if kol_tipov + 1  == Id :
            connection.close()
            break

        if not obgect_list :
            Id += 1
            PAGE = 0
            #print(Id)
            continue

        print(Id)



        for i in obgect_list :
            img = i.find('img',class_='card-img').get('src')

            name = i.find('div',class_='w-100 mt-auto').find('h5',class_='fs-6 card-title text-white').text
            url_img = f'https://mcbuild.org{img}'
            data_id = i.find('div').get('data-id')
            pytt_file_imgg =  download_img(url_img,data_id)
            pytt_file_schem = download_file(data_id)

            print(f'{n} {name}  {pytt_file_imgg} {pytt_file_schem}')

            Sqlite_base_loading(name,soup,pytt_file_imgg,pytt_file_schem,PAGE,connection)


            n += 1     
        
        PAGE +=1

click_more()



Просто парсер парсит названия, тип построек, ссылки изоброжений и файлов со схемами и с помощью функций выше скачивает  фото и схемы а потом функции  возвращают путь до этих файлов и это все записывается в бд , но не могу  понять почему программа в рандомный момент может просто остановится на вечно без ошибок .

Если скрипт при этом потребляет CPU, то скорее всего образовался бесконечный цикл(у вас потенциально это while True). Если потребления CPU нет, то смотрите в сторону сетевых запросов, может БД перестала отвечать, а вы ожидаете ответ.

@SwaD ну у меня комп  слабенкий  где посмотреть потребление цпу и  где можно узнать что бд перестала отвечать   .

Вбейте в поиск название вашей ОС и как посмотреть потребляемы ресурсы процессами... По поводу БД - натыкать логирование в вашем коде, что бы было понятно, после чего и где все останавливается.
